# How to chain PBS script?

Tags: bash, sh, bioinformatics, hpc, pbs

I am trying to run this bit of PBS code where I want to run part 2 after finishing part1, but for some reason it doesn't execute part2 after finishing part1. How can I make this execute part 2 in one go?

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -N AOGC_Contest
#PBS -l walltime=10:00:00
#PBS -l mem=10gb
#PBS -J 0-2

cd /mypath

##module load java ##AN commented out
##module load gatk ##AN commented out


SNP=/mypath/file.vcf
TMPDIR=/mypath/Contest/data/test_tmpdir/
FASTA=/mypath/Contest/data/hg19.fasta
CONTAMINATION=/mypath/Contest/data/test_contamination/
POPFILE=/mypath/Contest/data/hg19_CHR_FIXED.vcf

BAMS=( /mypath//S05-F13-P01_C06A1ACXX-1-13.ReCal.sort.bam /mypath//S08-F10-P01_C06A1ACXX-2-13.ReCal.sort.bam /mypath//AOGC-02-0010_C0J43ACXX-4-13.ReCal.sort.bam ) 

SAMPS=( S05-F13-P01 S08-F10-P01 AOGC-02-0010 ) 

BAM=${BAMS[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]}
SAM=${SAMPS[$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX]}

#BAM=${BAMS[1]}
#SAM=${SAMPS[1]}

echo "$SAM"
```

part1

```
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
-T SelectVariants \
-U ALLOW_SEQ_DICT_INCOMPATIBILITY \
-R ${FASTA} \
-V $SNP  \
-o ${TMPDIR}/${SAM}_${PBS_ARRAY_INDEX}.vcf \
-nt 4 \
--excludeNonVariants \
--removeUnusedAlternates \
--keepOriginalAC \
--keepOriginalDP \
-sn ${SAM}
```

part2

```
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
-T ContEst \
-U ALLOW_SEQ_DICT_INCOMPATIBILITY \
-I ${BAM} \
-R ${FASTA} \
--popfile ${POPFILE}  \
--genotypes:VCF4 ${TMPDIR}/${SAM}_$PBS_ARRAY_INDEX.vcf  \
-o ${CONTAMINATION}/contamination_${SAM}_${PBS_ARRAY_INDEX}.txt
```

Comment: Did you try to investigate why the second command did not start (failed to complete)? If you did please share the results. As it stands there are plenty of unnecessary details and a lot of important information missing in this post.

Comment: No, I haven't been able to figure that out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Like any program, a shell script "doesn't work" when there's some difference between intention and fact.  In your case, it looks to me like the variables aren't being set as you intend.

```
$ SAMPS=( S05-F13-P01 S08-F10-P01 AOGC-02-0010 ) 
$ echo $SAMPS
S05-F13-P01
```

If you want SAMPS to have the whole string, including whitespace, quote it:

```
$ SAMPS='S05-F13-P01 S08-F10-P01 AOGC-02-0010'
$ echo $SAMPS
S05-F13-P01 S08-F10-P01 AOGC-02-0010
```

(I don't recommend including leading and trailing whitespace.  It's easy enough to add when you use the variable.)

As a general debugging technique, `$ bash -x scriptname` will show you how your variables are expanded.  You can also sprinkle  `set -x` and `set +x` in your script to make it more verbose in problem areas.

HTH.